# How to use regex to disallow non-digts but allow a dot in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am new to regex and trying to remove all **non-digts** but keep the **dot** (**.**) of a string:

```
x = ['ABCD, EFGH ', ' 20.9&dog; ', ' IJKLM />']
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
>>> x = re.sub("\D", "", x)
209
```

However I am trying to get the following outcome:

```
20.9
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an inverted character class:

```
re.sub(r"[^\d.]", "", x)
```

Note that `[^0-9.]` and `[^\d.]` are not the same, because `\d` matches many more characters than just `0123456789`:

```
>>> print(textwrap.fill(
...    "".join(x for x in (chr(y) for y in range(0x110000))
...            if re.match(r"\d", x)),
...    break_long_words=True, width=10))
0123456789
٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩
۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹
߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈߉
०१२३४५६७८९
০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯
੦੧੨੩੪੫੬੭੮੯
૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯
୦୧୨୩୪୫୬୭୮୯
௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮௯
౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౯
೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯
൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮൯
෦෧෨෩෪෫෬෭෮෯
๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘๙
໐໑໒໓໔໕໖໗໘໙
༠༡༢༣༤༥༦༧༨༩
၀၁၂၃၄၅၆၇၈၉
႐႑႒႓႔႕႖႗႘႙
០១២៣៤៥៦៧៨៩
᠐᠑᠒᠓᠔᠕᠖᠗᠘᠙
᥆᥇᥈᥉᥊᥋᥌᥍᥎᥏
᧐᧑᧒᧓᧔᧕᧖᧗᧘᧙
᪀᪁᪂᪃᪄᪅᪆᪇᪈᪉
᪐᪑᪒᪓᪔᪕᪖᪗᪘᪙
᭐᭑᭒᭓᭔᭕᭖᭗᭘᭙
᮰᮱᮲᮳᮴᮵᮶᮷᮸᮹
᱀᱁᱂᱃᱄᱅᱆᱇᱈᱉
᱐᱑᱒᱓᱔᱕᱖᱗᱘᱙
꘠꘡꘢꘣꘤꘥꘦꘧꘨꘩
꣐꣑꣒꣓꣔꣕꣖꣗꣘꣙
꤀꤁꤂꤃꤄꤅꤆꤇꤈꤉
꧐꧑꧒꧓꧔꧕꧖꧗꧘꧙
꧰꧱꧲꧳꧴꧵꧶꧷꧸꧹
꩐꩑꩒꩓꩔꩕꩖꩗꩘꩙
꯰꯱꯲꯳꯴꯵꯶꯷꯸꯹
０１２３４５６７８９
```

I bet you didn't know there were so many variations of the [Hindu-Arabic numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu%E2%80%93Arabic_numeral_system).

It's also worth mentioning that even in the latest 3.x, Python's regular expressions do **not** support [POSIX ERE named character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) (scroll down to "character classes" -- sadly, there is no anchor).  `[^[:digit:].]` won't do what you want.

Comment: Won't it leave DOT in `AB.CD` intact?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, it will.  Extracting decimal numbers would require a syntactic definition of "decimal number", a more complicated RE, and different surrounding code, and it's not what was asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the class `\D` you can define your own class of characters using `[...]`, and invert that class using `[^...]`. Now just put all the digits `0-9` and the `.` into that class:

```
>>> x = ['ABCD, EFGH ', ' 20.9&dog; ', ' IJKLM />']
>>> [re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", y) for y in x]
['', '20.9', '']
```

Of course, instead of *removing* everything that is *not* a number or dot, you could also use `re.findall` or `re.search` to get those parts of the string that *are* numbers or dot. This has the benefit that if the string contains more than one number, those will not clump together:

```
>>> z = "foo20.9bar42.1blub"
>>> re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", z)
'20.942.1'
>>> re.findall("[0-9.]+", z)
['20.9', '42.1']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple requirement which can be made explicit:

```
for item in x:
    print re.sub(r'[^0-9.]', "", item)
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers have this issue of skipping DOT without making sure that DOT is actually part of a decimal number. Hence a string like `Mr.Bean` will remain `Mr.Bean` since DOT is is part of the negative character class (exclusion list).

To fix tihs issue you can use this negative lookahead regex:

```
>>> re.sub(r"(?!\.\d)\D", "", ' 20.9&dog; ')
'20.9'
```

`(?!\.\d)` asserts that when we match `\D` we don't have a DOT and a digit ahead.